# import two external libraries in JniLibs folder( android - NDK )

Tags: android-studio, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I'm making a app which needs two library (opencv, dlib)

I have .so file(armeabi-v7a version)

But, I have a problem of importing two libraries in JniLibs folder.

when I import both of them like below, my app doesn't work

JniLibs

------opencv

-------------- armeabi-v7a .so

------dlib

-------------- armeabi-v7a .so

what should I do to use both of libraries?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

libraries for `armeabi-v7a` should be put into `jniLibs/armeabi-v7a` folder directly